# Validate all revisions in SVN + Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins, continuous-integration

Trying to setup a continuous integration system. We are using SVN for source control. Now I want to validate(build) each revision using jenkins. By default jenkins just builds the latest revision. We commit very frequently and therefore it is important to validate each revision.

Note : Currently we use an inhouse developed utility that update the working copy to the next revision and builds it. It then sends out build results(fail/success) accordingly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup Subversion hook for start build: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin#SubversionPlugin-Postcommithook

Comment: Won't this create a problem if we commit too frequently. The build takes about 15 minutes. What happens if there are multiple commits during that time?

Comment: All jobs will be queued and wait. By default Jenkins run only 2 jobs simultaneously. Though as I understand this (build **every** revision) required. If it is allowed to combine revisions into bunches, then you can use standard SCM Poll trigger and set polling intervat to 1 minute.

Comment: Does jenkins run different instances of the same job together ? Cos this could cause build errors. If all the post commit jobs are queued up, I would like all the queued jobs to to run one bu one. This will solve my problem.

Comment: Job has configuration itme `Execute concurrent builds if necessary`. AFAIK it is unchecked by default, so Jenkins will execute queued jobs one-by-one

Comment: Thanks :)
 I will give it a go and mark this as the answer if it works well.